# How to get amp-youtube videos to play on button press? on=tap:id.play does not consistently work

Tags: amp-html, amp-youtube

I am trying to create a video overlay, or a button that will start playing the amp-youtube video. However, the button seems to work once in a blue moon. Most times it will pre-load/buffer the video but will not actually start playing. The user must click on the video again to start playing.

If it works the first time, refresh the page and it won't work again.
[AMP Playground Example](https://playground.amp.dev/#share=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)

Comment: What the problem? As expected, the buttons work and the inline controls work.

Comment: @Jay Gray please try using a desktop browser. It is neither working for me on Chrome nor Safari.